# WPF get different value from ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

My ComboBox looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbMDLName" Style="{StaticResource ComoboBox}"     
DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MDLCollection}" 
SelectionChanged="cbMDLName_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

The DataContext is set from the code behind file. 
`this.DataContext = this.ManagerRoot.MDLM;`

The ItemSource of the ComboBox is set to `ObservableCollection<MDL> MDLCollection {get;set;}`.

`MDL.cs`

```
public class MDL : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AdditionManager AdditionManager { get; set; }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set 
        { 
            this._name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private int _index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return this._index; }
        set 
        { 
            this._index = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the index from the selected entry. How can I do that?

Comment: var yourSelection=(MDL)cbMDLName.SelectedItem; you will get the index in yourSelection.Index

Comment: @riteshmeher I mean the index of the selected object. As example in this ComoBox are 3 entrys. Each of this entry got one `Name` and one `Index`. The `Name` is shown in the ComboBox and the `Index` not. 
My question is now: How can I get the related `Index`?

Comment: Try SelectedValue?

Comment: @riteshmeher now it's working. Thanks!  Please edit your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this.

```
int selectedValue = (int)cbMDLName.SelectedValue;
```